# 403 when uploading json string via rest (c#)

Tags: c#, mysql, json, rest

actually I´m trying to get tables in my codeBeamer - mysql updated via the REST services from CodeBeamer. So I´m downloading some tables, compare them with others and upload the new table to the CodeBeamer database. It all works fine but when it comes to uploading the converted JSON string I get the 403 exception.

What I tried so far:

- Logging in as server admin via credentials
- PUT and POST method
- uploading every row separately

This is the code I use to upload the json string:

`

```
string jsonFinal;
 DataTable _dtJasonRoles = _dtRolesEdit.Clone();
 _dtJasonRoles.Rows.Add(_dtJasonRoles.NewRow());
 for (int i = 0; i < _dtRolesEdit.Rows.Count; i++)
 {
       _dtJasonRoles.Rows[0]["uri"] = _dtRolesEdit.Rows[i]["uri"];
       _dtJasonRoles.Rows[0]["name"] = _dtRolesEdit.Rows[i]["name"];
       _dtJasonRoles.Rows[0]["description"] = _dtRolesEdit.Rows[i]["description"];
       jsonFinal = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_dtJasonRoles, Formatting.Indented);                                                            
       Console.WriteLine(jsonFinal);                                                                                                           
       string result = "";
       client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json";
       result = client.UploadString("http://*server*:*port*/cb/rest/role", "PUT", jsonFinal);
       Console.WriteLine(result);
 }
```

`

What the code should do:
Converting row after row from the "_dtRolesEdit" data table into json and uploading it to the database.

Console output:

`

```
[
  {
    "uri": "/role/*number*",
    "name": "*name*",
    "description": "n/a"
  }
]
```

`

After hours of research and troubleshooting you are my last hope. 
Do you know how to fix this. I can´t even imagine where my fault could be.

Best regards

Comment: Have you tried sending the message using Fiddler composer?
Also: what kind of credentials need to be used? Is it something that needs to be added to the http header?

Comment: I did not use the Fiddler composer yet. The UID and the PWD are required for the credentials. Without that I get no permissions. The credentials are saved in the "client" so they are added to the header if I am not mistaken?

I will do some research about the Fiddler composer. Thanks for your help so far.

Answer (score 1):

Luckily I found the problem together with my colleague. The problem was, that I had subjects in my table that I need to change and subjects that I need to add. So the first problem was I had PUT and POST requests in the same data table. The second problem was that the first row in my data table should be added to the existing table in CodeBeamer. So if you POST sth to CodeBeamer you don´t need the URI in your JSON because the REST API generates the URI for new rows automatically.
Now I have to POST the new Items and PUT the changes separately and everything is working fine.

Greets

Comment: Good to hear you found the solution :)